# Windows 7 "Computer" menu never loads

Tags: windows-7

Pressing Windows 7 "Computer" icon in start panel opens Computer window. The progress bar starts to move slowly, but screen never loads. Ends up not responding. Any suggestions how to solve my problem? 
P.s.: I have all appropriate drivers and Avast antivirus

Comment: You may have a faulty ROM drive. Turn off the machine, unplug the DVD-ROM, restart, and see if it does the same thing. Rinse and repeat for USB drives.

Comment: @Randolph Why not post this as an answer to I can vote it up?

Comment: Disconnecting DVD didn't help. I don't expect it to be a hardware problem, OpenSUSE worked flawlessly. Thank you for suggestion though

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try:

- You may have a faulty ROM drive. Turn off the machine, unplug the DVD-ROM, restart, and see if it does the same thing. Rinse and repeat for USB drives.
- You may have a driver problem. Did you install drivers off the manufacturer's website for your chipset, or did you use the Windows Update drivers? That could be something to look into as well.
- Try `chkdsk` on the main drive.
- Check that you don't have an IDE or SATA cable plugged into the motherboard that isn't connected to a device.

Comment: Just to add one thing, running "sfc /scannow" may resolve a DLL or driver problem. You run the command at the run prompt or a admin CMD

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833 See link on how to use the sfc utility.

Answer (score 0):

i've experienced this a handful of times on Windows 7. i didn't know what caused it, but killing the Explorer process, and relaunching it fixed it. (a reboot would have the same effect).

i also recognize that if i try to access my 3rd hard drive after it has spun down: i have to wait 6-7 seconds before Windows Explorer will respond - as it waits for the drive platters to spin up. Nothing can fix this, except for changing the power policy to not let the drives spin down (which i'm not going to do).